# Send lat/lng to view

Tags: flask

I'am using Google maps with Flask to get lat/lng when the map is clicked:

```
<div id="latclicked"></div>
<div id="longclicked"></div>

 google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(event) {
     document.getElementById('latclicked').innerHTML = event.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById('longclicked').innerHTML =  event.latLng.lng();
```

What is the simplest way to send the lat/lng to the view ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about a form?

Javascript

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        document.getElementById('lat').value = event.latLng.lat()
        document.getElementById('lng').value = event.latLng.lng()
    });
```

HTML

```
<form method=post>
  Lat: <input id = "lat" type="text" name="lat"><br>
  Lng: <input id = "lng" type="text" name="lng"
  <input type=submit value=Submit>
</form>
```

You could make the input fields readonly so that the only way to have the values there is clicking map with a placeholder "click on map for lat" etc